# What does the phrase "baize to secure early lead" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

I cannot figure out the meaning of the phrase "battle of the baize" in the following heading of a [news item](https://theboar.org/2017/02/varsity-2017-warwick-win-battle-baize-secure-early-lead/):

> Varsity 2017: Warwick win **battle of the baize** to secure early lead

I am not sure if the phrase above simply means "a game of billiard".

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a metaphor. Baize is the cloth used to cover billiards/snooker tables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of "metonymy", using an attribute of something to stand for the thing itself.  For example saying "Three suits came to the farm" meaning "Three business executives wearing suits". You should think of more examples in your own language, as this rhetorical technique is not limited to English.

In this case, "baize" is the soft, usually green, cloth which covers snooker, billiard and pool tables. The "battle of the baize" is a competition. Reading the rest of the article it is clear that it is a pool competition, and part of an inter-university competition between Warwick and Coventry (two universities based in the same English city of Coventry)